# Consideration on how long AudioWorkletProcessor.process should run

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api, audio-worklet

Since a call to `AudioWorkletProcessor.process` is synchronous according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletProcessor/process, what happens when an execution takes too long time, more than 1 second, for example? Would some audio samples be skipped in a next call? Or would samples be queued somewhere? I could not find a documentation on this.

Answer (score 4):

A realtime `AudioContext` is usually tight to a certain physical audio output device. Therefore the `currentTime` of an `AudioContext` is driven by the hardware clock of that audio output device.

If the `AudioContext` somehow fails to deliver the samples in time the result will be silence. Typically that can be heard as a click sound if there is suddenly a little bit of silence where it shouldn't be. The samples that took too long to render will then be used for the next render quantum if they happen to be ready by then.

There is a difference though in how browsers advance the `currentTime` in case some samples couldn't be delivered in time. Firefox seems to not count any missed samples whereas Chrome progresses time counting all samples that the audio hardware spit out including those that couldn't be rendered in time.

To test this I created an `AudioWorkletProcessor` that can be paused or blocked from within the main thread.

```
class BlockableProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
    constructor () {
        super();

        this.int32Array = null;
        this.port.onmessage = ({ data }) => this.int32Array = data;
    }

    process() {
        if (this.int32Array !== null) {
            while (Atomics.load(this.int32Array, 0) === 0) {
                Atomics.store(this.int32Array, 1, currentTime);
            }

            Atomics.store(this.int32Array, 1, currentTime);
        }

        return true;
    }
}

registerProcessor('blockable-processor', BlockableProcessor);
```

This `BlockableProcessor` expects to receive a `SharedArrayBuffer` which it uses to check if it should block the `process()` function or not. And it also uses it to communicate the `currentTime` back to the main thread.

It can be used like this:

```
const audioWorkletNode = new AudioWorkletNode(
    audioContext,
    'blockable-processor'
);
const sharedArrayBuffer = new SharedArrayBuffer(8);
const int32Array = new Int32Array(sharedArrayBuffer);

Atomics.store(int32Array, 0, 1);
Atomics.store(int32Array, 1, 0);

audioWorkletNode.port.postMessage(int32Array);
audioWorkletNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
```

It can be blocked by setting the first value of the `SharedArrayBuffer` to 0.

```
Atomics.store(int32Array, 0, 0);
```

And likewise it can be unblocked again by setting it to 1 again.

```
Atomics.store(int32Array, 0, 1);
```

It's also possible to read the `currentTime` written from within the `AudioWorkletProcessor` on the main thread.

```
Atomics.load(int32Array, 1);
```

Using this setup I was able to see that Chrome (v95) and Firefox (v93) both stop the time progression on the main thread and in the worklet in case the processor is blocked.

When it gets unblocked Firefox continues where it stopped and Chrome continues where it should be if everything would have been going as expected.

Comment: Isn't the issue you linked to about *output* devices, i.e kind of `setSinkId()` for AudioContext? My headphone has almost no computational power, being able to switch to it instead of the default audio output won't help much in this case ;-)

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. The issue is not really related to my answer. I removed the link. I think in case of your headphone the audio output device would not be the headphone itself but the internal soundcard or an external soundcard. Unless it's not a Bluetooth headphone which comes with its own soundcard. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is a good answer with test code included, which is useful for experimenting more. 

Quick follow up questions. 1) Do you know what happens to the next input samples if `AudioWorkletProcessor` is blocked? 2) Do you have a theoretical threshold on how long `AudioWorkletProcessor` can block before a skip happens (what's the value for too long)?

Comment: It looks like the whole audio graph is blocked when an `AudioWorkletProcessor` takes too long. In that sense I would say nothing happens. It's as if the world would stand still for a moment. :-) I couldn't see any limit in my tests. I blocked the `AudioWorkletProcessor` for several minutes. But I think that was just luck or maybe because I ran the page from localhost. In practice I believe that browser vendors will kill the audio thread as they probably think you're abusing it.